# Word 2007 Automation - Images show up as black boxes when printed

Tags: c#, image, printing, interop, ms-word

When I use the Word 2007 Interop to print it does not show the images in the printed copy.  It just shows black boxes for placeholders.  However, when it is printed manually from Word (without the Interop) it is fine.

> If some graphics are not printing (or not displaying in Print Preview),
>   go to Office Button | Word Options | Display: Printing options and make
>   sure that “Print drawings created in
>   Word” is checked.

I tried setting

```
Options.PrintDrawingObject = true;
```

but there was no effect.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting the other options like "Print background colors and images"? Also have you tried with older versions of Word (Word 2003)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there seems to be a bug in word 2007 that causes this issue.  It is due to the way images are linked when saved.

```
Select all (CTRL + A)
Click on the Office Icon (circular icon in top left corner)
Go to prepare
Click on "edit links to files"
Check the "save picture in document" box
Click ok
Save
```

I have not figured out a way to do this in the interop (I think there is a way to automate the hotkeys, but that feels like a hack).